# Batch, Using variables to form a command

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I am trying to make a simple Arma 2 launcher that launches with a specific set of mods, but the execute paramaters of Arma2OA.exe wont use %Variable%, instead It needs to use the defined Variables to create a command and execute it. How would I do such a thing? Here is what I have thus far

Note: The %Variables% in the executable launch parameters do not work, that just shows where they take place

```
@echo off
:: Variable Table
set Arma2OA_Dir="F:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 2 Operation Arrowhead"
set Arma2_Dir="F:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 2"
set Mod_Dir="F:\Program Files\Arma 2 Mods\"
set CPU_Count=8
set Max_Mem=6144
::

cd /d %Arma2OA_Dir%

:: The Executable
ArmA2OA.exe -cpuCount=%CPU_Count% -noSplash -maxMem=%Max_Mem% -exThreads=7 -high -world=empty -noPause "-mod=%Arma2_Dir%;Expansion;ca;%Mod_Dir%@ace;%Mod_Dir%@acex;%Mod_Dir%@acex_ru;
::

pause
```

Comment: Rolled back to OP's original version. Proposed edits changed the user's original code introducing a possibly-significant space.

Comment: I think you have a " character that isn't closed in your question, right?

Comment: Yes, that " wasn't closed because I was fiddling about with the code to make it look neater. But it wasn't significant. I actually am baffled, as to why Arma does not work with a string of multiple mods, but it seems to work with only a few mods. I guess the issue is Arma, (what else is new)

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. Quotation marks are not allowed after the -mod string, so having the locations in "s was a mistake. Instead I have to put the whole -mod string in quotes!

Answer (score 0):

```
set executable=ArmA2OA.exe -cpuCount=%CPU_Count% -noSplash -maxMem=%Max_Mem% -exThreads=7 -high -world=empty -noPause "-mod=%Arma2_Dir%;Expansion;ca;%Mod_Dir%@ace;%Mod_Dir%@acex;%Mod_Dir%@acex_ru;
%executable%
```

should work if your problem-analysis is correct.

Comment: @djangofan please add a comment about the changes you edited-in. It would appear that you broke the `set` command over three lines but did not fix the unbalanced-quotes problem you highlight. Perhaps you meant to insert an extra quote after the `...@acex_ru;` which is reasonable, but unfortunately you added a `^` not a `"`. That would render the `%executable%` as part of the `SET` command and disble the intent, to execute `ArmA2OA.exe` after having manually completed the command. I believe that you are probably quite right about the need for the closing `"` which could fix the original.

Comment: I didn't try to fix the quote.  I added the carrot just to make your answer more readable without having to scroll to the right.  Carrots are used to extend one line to multiple lines although when quotes are involved you need to be careful about using carrots or it will break the line extension.